# Jquery class change hover over effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, mouseenter

Is there a better way to do the following?:

```
$('.favorite').mouseenter(function(){
    var el = $(this);
    if(el.hasClass('fa-star-o')) {
        el.removeClass('fa-star-o');
        el.addClass('fa-star');

        el.mouseleave(function(){
            el.removeClass('fa-star');
            el.addClass('fa-star-o').unbind('mouseleave');
        })
    }
})
```

It's for a simple hover over effect using font-awesome classes.

Comment: Use `el.toggleClass("fa-star fa-star-o");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the cleanest way is to use jquery functions [hover()](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) and [toggleClass()](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) :

```
$('.favorite').hover(function(){
     $(this).toggleClass("fa-star fa-star-o"); 
});
```